# how to auto adjust design for all simulators

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, device, screen-size

I am developing an application with the 9630 BlackBerry simulator, but when I test with the 9550 simulator, my app draws off-screen.   How do I adjust for all simulators to avoid this?

Comment: You've asked this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066784/ui-compatibility-across-all-blackberry-devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using HorisontalFieldManager and VerticalFieldManager (aspecially with USE_ALL_WIDTH, USE_ALL_HEIGHT style flags) makes life easier.

Also remember about using scroll inside field managers (ex. for vertical lists)

Talking about image resources, like backgrounds etc, there are several ways you can go:

- separated image resources for each screen size + ant file to copy/delete during device-specific build
- separated image resources for each screen size + runtime screen size check and resource selection by filename
- runtime image resources generation (like 9 patch in Android)
- try to avoid use of image resources, and use gradient or solid backgrounds

See also
[Blackberry User Interface Design - Customizable UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445953/blackberry-user-interface-design-customizable-ui)
[developing application for diffrent screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024263/developing-application-for-diffrent-screen-size)
[Supporting multiple screens - Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496175/supporting-multiple-screens-blackberry)
[UI compatibility across all BlackBerry devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066784/ui-compatibility-across-all-blackberry-devices)